# Postfix smtpd_client_restrictions with check_client_access not working

Tags: postfix

I suddenly receive many spam mails per day and I’m trying to filter the source by IP.

In my `main.cf` file I have this:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
        check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/blacklist,
        permit
```

and in this `blacklist` file I have IP addresses and networks defined in the following way according to https://linux.die.net/man/5/access. I don’t filter by domain name since every spam has a different domain name.

```
1.2.3.4  REJECT Blacklisted
5.6.7    REJECT Blacklisted
```

I used `cdb`previously and it was working perfectly, except for networks (`5.6.7`). I switched to `cidr` which is apparently recommended, but I still get spam although the *network* is in my blacklist file.

I did the `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/blacklist && sudo postfix reload` after adding the network to the blacklist file, but it didn’t filter the spam mail.

Answer (score 2):

**Specify explicit network mask.**

The syntax for the [`cidr` table](https://linux.die.net/man/5/cidr_table) is different from simpler indexed files (such as DB or DBM), it expects an explicit mask - and uses it to allow for much nicer representation of [blocks smaller or bigger than /8 /16 /24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks).

```
# network_address/network_mask result
192.0.2.0/24     REJECT Blacklisted
203.0.113.128/28 REJECT Blacklisted
```

Test your file using `postmap -q`:

```
# postmap -q 203.0.113.144 cidr:/path/to/example.cidr
# postmap -q 203.0.113.143 cidr:/path/to/example.cidr
REJECT Blacklisted
```

A warning will be emitted for syntax problems, no result will be printed for IPs not matching any listed network.

Comment: Apparently my version of postfix doesn't support CIDR table. I tried that. The only thing that works (finally) is with CDB and with IP address defined as in access manual, 1.2.3.4 or 1.2.3 for subnets.

Comment: Sorry, just checked again with `postconf -m` and cidr is supported. I had an error when I tried to use it. Cidr is definitely better. To generate the database, do you also call `postconf cidr:ip_to_blacklist` ?

Comment: @chmike The manual does not mention anything about `cidr` type tables making use of the `postmap`-generated indexed databases. Unsurprisingly, as the prefixes are checked in the order as specified in the table anyway.